# Cannot allow external traffic through ISTIO

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to setup Istio and I need to whitelist few ports for allowing non mTLS traffic from outside world coming in through specfic port for few pods runnings in local k8s.

I am unable to find a successful way of doing it.

Tried Service entry, policy and destination rule and didnt succeed.

Helps is highly appreciated.

````
version.BuildInfo{Version:"1.1.2", GitRevision:"2b1331886076df103179e3da5dc9077fed59c989", User:"root", Host:"35adf5bb-5570-11e9-b00d-0a580a2c0205", GolangVersion:"go1.10.4", DockerHub:"docker.io/istio", BuildStatus:"Clean", GitTag:"1.1.1"}```

Service Entry
```apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-traffic
  namespace: cloud-infra
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*.cluster.local"
  ports:
  - number: 50506
    name: grpc-xxx
    protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: NONE```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a DestinationRule and a Policy :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: destinationrule-test
spec:
  host: service-name
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 8080
      tls:
        mode: DISABLE
---
apiVersion: authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: policy-test
spec:
  targets:
  - name: service-name
    ports:
    - number: 8080
  peers:
```

This has been tested with istio 1.0, but it will probably work for istio 1.1. It is heavily inspired by the documentation https://istio.io/help/ops/setup/app-health-check/

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understood that you want to control your [ingress traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/) allow some ports to your services that functioning in your mesh/cluster from outside, but your configuration is for [egress traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/).

In order to control and allow ports to your services from outside, you can follow these steps.

1.Make sure that `containerPort` included to your deployment/pod configuration. 
For more [info](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/prepare/requirements/)

2.You have to have service pointing to your backends/pods. For more info about [Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).
3.Then in your Istio enabled cluster, you have to create `Gateway` similar to below configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: your-service-gateway
  namespace: foo-namespace # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: HTTP
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

4.Then configure route to your service for traffic entering via the this `gateway` by creating `VirtualService`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: your-service
  namespace: foo-namespace # Use same namespace with backend service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - your-service-gateway # define gateway name
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 3000 # Backend service port
        host: your-service # Backend service name
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I want to allow traffic from services outside the mesh and what you recommended worked like a charm. Thanks @coollinuxoid

Comment: If this helped, I would kindly ask you to accept this answer. Thanks